# python set returns the first item only

Tags: python

The purpose of this script is to send an email to a receivers list, and the code works just for the first receiver but the never works for the rest of the list.

here is the code:

```
class email:
    def __init__(self, sender, subject, message):
        self.sender = sender
        self.subject = subject
        self.message = message



    def receivers(self):
        receivers = ('adam', 'tom', 'mel')
        for receiver in receivers:
            return receiver



    def send(self):
        print('we send email from'.capitalize(), self.sender, 'to', email.receivers().title(), 'and the subject is',
              self.subject, 'finally the massage is', self.message)


email = email('sayed', 'morning message', 'wake up man')
email.send()
```

here is the result:

```
We send email from sayed to Adam and the subject is morning message finally the massage is wake up man
```

Comment: you return on the first iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Return` exits the function once it returns a value. It's like a `break`.

You get that result, because once you return the first value ('adam'), you exit the function via `return`. You should just `return` the whole tuple: `return receivers`, then in `send(self)`:

```
receivers = email.receivers()
for receiver in receivers:
    print('we send email from'.capitalize(), self.sender, 'to', receiver.title(), 'and the subject is',
              self.subject, 'finally the massage is', self.message)
```

Answer (score 4):

Whenever a `return` statement is executed, the current function is immediately exited. Use either `return receivers` (without the loop) to return the entire set instead of just one item, or use `yield receiver` to create a [*generator*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/626853) (if you choose the latter, please read the linked answer to understand what generators are).

Stylistic advice: reusing a function name as a variable name inside that function is likely going to confuse people who read your code.

Answer (score 0):

your receivers function stops after returning the first receiver, I suggest returning the set and iterate over it

```
def receivers(self):
    return ('adam', 'tom', 'mel')

for receiver in email.receivers():
    print('we send email from'.capitalize(), self.sender, 'to', receiver.title(), 'and the subject is',
          self.subject, 'finally the massage is', self.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

If tuple of receivers is static, then move this tuple to be class attribute:

```
class Email: # convenient
  _receivers = ('adam', 'tom', 'mel') # _ - to be protected
```